# React - update object in state

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I need to update an object in state, but only some of its elements. So if it has 7 elements, and my new object has 4, those 4 should replace the existing ones while the rest should be preserved.

Here is an example component which outputs the current object keys and values in the state. When you press the button, the object should get updated with new values on some of its properties. Right now it is overwriting the object with the 4 elements, so I need to modify it. See the handleClick method.

In my real project the object is inside redux state, but I guess the solution will be the same. I get the new properties from a form that is posted, so I have an object like the one below named "update".

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import Button from 'material-ui-next/Button';
import Menu, { MenuItem } from 'material-ui-next/Menu';

class UpdateObject extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

         this.state = {

            theObject : {

                token: '478478478478',
                firstName: 'Goofy',
                lastName: 'Hello',
                age: '14',
                sex: 'female',
                employed: true,
                favoriteColor: 'Blue',
                bio: 'details of bio',
                }
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }


  handleClick(){

      let update = {
            age: '40',
            lastName: 'Newname',
            employed: true,
            favoriteColor: 'Yellow',
      }

    let change = Object.assign({}, this.state.theObject);
        change = update;

        this.setState({ theObject: change });

  }

 render() {
    const myObj = this.state.theObject;

        return (

            <div className="updateobjectwrapper bl">
    <div> Here is the current object: <br />

        <ul> 
        { Object.entries(myObj).map(([ key,value ] ) => {

            return (
                   <li key={key}>{key} : {value} </li>
                 )
            })     
        }
        </ul>

        </div> 
            <Button  
              onClick={this.handleClick}
            >
              Update Object
            </Button>
        </div>
    ) 

 }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass multiple arguments to [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Examples) method and it will merge all of them.

```
handleClick(){
    let update = {
            age: '40',
            lastName: 'Newname',
            employed: true,
            favoriteColor: 'Yellow',
    }

    let change = Object.assign({}, this.state.theObject, update);

    this.setState({ theObject: change });
}
```